# Error when adding commas to number

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to get the helper to return a number with commas (eg 100000 = 100,000). It is returning correctly however I getting an error appearing in my console.

`Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

If I `console.log(value);` it returns `undefined`.

Path: `test.js`

```
Template.registerHelper(
    'formatCurrency', function(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    },
);
```

Path: `test.html`

```
{{formatCurrency compareSalary.userSalary}}
{{formatCurrency compareSalary.min}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common failure in helpers is that the data isn't back from a subscription by the time you try to render it. This can be prevented by testing the value before returning it:

```
Template.registerHelper(
  'formatCurrency',(value)=>{
    return value && value.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  },
);
```